# How are Firefox and other long lived sockets terminated when I lock my session?

Tags: xfce, firefox, light-locker

When I lock my session on xfce, Firefox and apps that rely on socket connections get their connections terminated. I find such behavior bizarre. I haven't been able to figure out why it happens or how it happens or how to disable it. I've tested with http/XMLHttpRequest ping and they are kept, but WebSockets go down as soon I lock the screen. Is there a reason for this behavior and how to disable?

Comment: I suspect the OS will be quite relevant here. Should we assume a Linux?

Comment: @terdon Although, I haven't tested any other system, Debian doesn't include any relevant patch that isn't also included on vanilla xfce.

Comment: Sure, I was just thinking that the behavior of sockets may depend on the OS. I wouldn't expect different Linux distros to behave differently, but presumably there are differences in how sockets work in different *nix systems, so telling us which one you use could help those more knowledgeable than I to answer you.

Comment: Aaaaand, I only now realized you're talking about [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), not [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). Sorry, you said it quite clearly in the question, but I missed it. I can't imagine the OS will be relevant here, you're quite right.